# Question about the angle $\theta$ Green's theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Given $Q(x,y)=x\cdot y^2+y \ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ and $P(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ calculate the integral $\int_C P\,dx+Q\,dy$ while $C=(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=1$

I used Greens theorem and got $Q_x-P_y=y^2$ so we need the double integral $\iint_S y^2\,ds$ so since this is a moved circle we use $x=1+r\cos\theta$ and $y=1+r\sin\theta$ and according to the graph we should take $0 \leq r \leq 1$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ but that way when I integrate I get a wrong answer $\frac{5\pi}{16}-\frac{2}{3}$ when the correct answer is $\frac{5\pi}{4}$ I tried to randomly take $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ I get a correct answer

my question is why $\theta$ should be until $2\pi$? I cannot seem to understand this.. the teacher told me I should move it to the center but I cannot see a reason for that can anyone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are familiar with translation and rotation of coordinate system. To explain, you now have new coordinate axes $X, Y$ where
$X = x - 1, Y = y - 1$.

So new coordinates of $(1,1)$ is $(0, 0)$, the new origin of XY coordinate system.

Equation of the circle $(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 \leq 1$ in the new coordinate system is $X^2 + Y^2 \leq 1$ which is a circle of radius $1$ centered at the origin.

Now in polar coordinates, $X = r \cos \theta, Y = r \sin \theta, \ 0 \leq r \leq 1, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi \ $, as it is a circle of radius $1$ centered at the origin.

Now note that $X = r \cos\theta = x - 1 \implies x = 1 + r \cos\theta$. Similarly $Y = 1 + r \sin\theta$.

So instead of writing it as two steps as above, we simply parametrize as,

$(1 + r \cos\theta, 1 + r\sin\theta), 0 \leq r \leq 1, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rotate by $2\pi$ to make a complete rotation about the circle. I assume you were thinking $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ made sense because the circle is only located within the first quadrant, but with the equations for $x$ and $y$ that you gave in terms of $r,\theta$, you should be able to see that the center is $(1,1)$ and you need to make a full rotation to trace the circle around this center. Imagine drawing the unit circle and then translating it $1$ unit in the positive $x$ direction and $1$ unit in the positive $y$ direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you have $x=1+r\cos\theta$ and $y=1+r\sin\theta$ then you need to consider the angle around point $(1,1)$, not around point $(0,0)$. Since $C$ is the full circle around point $(1,1)$, you need all angles $0\le \theta\le 2\pi$.